# VBA Excel runtime error with Outlook GetNamespace("MAPI")

Tags: excel, outlook

I am trying to get started with some basic code. I have Microsoft Office 2013 installed.  From Excel, I create a VBA module, code below. I have "Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library" selected as an included Reference.  When the execution gets to line 5, it throws a

> Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': Sorry something went wrong.  You may want to try again.

I'm not sure why this happening.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

1: Sub GetFromOutlook()

2:   Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application

3:   Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace

4:   Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

5:   Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

6:   Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing

7:   Set OutlookApp = Nothing

8: End Sub

Comment: What you want to achieve with this code.

Comment: The error is MAPI_E_INVALID_PARAMETER. Is Outlook running at the time your code is executed? Can Outlook be started manually?

Comment: The current goal is to just be able to access emails from Excel.  Regardless if Outlook is running or not (I've tried both with Outlook open and closed) it produces the same error.  Outlook can be started manually.  This is also a work computer (not a personal computer).  Could it be that my IT department has removed messaging interfaces?